# Can I number a group of examples: 1, 2, 3... within any given section of a chapter while in the presence of subsections?

Tags: sectioning, formatting

I wish to number a set of two, three, four... examples within any given section of a chapter, beginning each set at No.1
Sorry, I am not able to construct a MWE on this occasion; I have no idea where to start.

Comment: If your examples correspond to a counter, say example, you just have to use in your preamble: `\counterwithin*{example}{section}`.

Comment: In addition to what @Bernard has suggested, the counter must be defined with `\refstep`.  If you want to start a new group, just reset the counter to 0.

Comment: Thanks, but what is the name of the counter if the example call is say \example? Is it \theexample ?

Comment: Please provide an example showing how the `example` environment is defined.

Comment: Using the standard \theoremstyle package in ams math.

Comment: Then yes, the theorem env and the counter it uses share the same name, here `example`. `\theexample` will display the counter `example`.

Comment: Tried these three commands; got down to one complex error to do with theorem definition. \newcounter{example}[section] % creates new counter example that will be reset every time the section counter is increased
% seems to work

\newcommand{\sno}[0]{\refstepcounter{example}$_{\roman{example}}$} % roman and arabic give same result

\counterwithin*{example}{section}

Comment: A bounty doesn't help here, you need to improve your question. Without an example that allows to detect which counter you actually use for your examples it is not possible to help you.

Comment: Thank you.  Now that I understand what is involved, would it be better to submit a new question with a MWE?

Comment: I believe I have found the problem.  The statement \counterwithin*{example}{section} has to be positioned after the declarations of example.

Comment: @keith77777 No need to post a new question. You can just edit this one.

Answer (score 1):

The statement \counterwithin*{example}{section} has to be positioned after the declaration of example.

Comment: It seems a comment. Please, can you explain better your answer putting a MWE? Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

\documentclass[english,11pt]{book}
%------------------------------------------------------------------------------------ %
%
\usepackage[fleqn]{amsmath} %
\usepackage{amsthm,amssymb} %
\usepackage{tikz} %
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc} %
\usepackage{newtxtext} %
\usepackage{newtxmath} %
\usepackage{xcolor} %
\usepackage[paperwidth=170mm,paperheight=240mm,textwidth=132mm,lmargin=12.5mm,rmargin=12.5mm,
bindingoffset=12.5mm,noheadfoot,nomarginpar,showframe,showcrop]{geometry} %
\usepackage[a4,frame,cam,center]{crop}
\usepackage{setspace}
\usepackage{colortbl} %
\usepackage{refcount} %
\usepackage{hyperref} %
%
%
\setlength{\unitlength}{1pt}
\setlength{\parskip}{0pt}
\setlength\parindent{0pt}

\definecolor{DarkRed}{rgb}{0.45,0.06,0.06} % #880000

\makeatletter
\newtheoremstyle{plain}
{4pt}                                           % ABOVESPACE
{2pt}                                           % BELOWSPACE
{\itshape}                              % BODYFONT
{6pt}                                           % INDENT (empty value is the same as 0pt)
{\color{DarkRed}\bfseries}% HEADFONT
{:.}                                           % HEADPUNCT
{5pt plus 1pt minus 1pt}    % HEADSPACE
{}                                              % CUSTOM-HEAD-SPEC
\newtheorem{theorem}{Theorem}
\makeatother

\counterwithin*{theorem}{section}

\begin{document}

\vspace*{12pt}
\section{Section ONE}

\begin{theorem}
Theorem 1
\end{theorem}

\begin{theorem}
Theorem 2
\end{theorem}

\section{Section TWO}

\begin{theorem}
Theorem 1
\end{theorem}

\begin{theorem}
Theorem 2
\end{theorem}

\end{document}